# Need to get vowel count of relevant array index

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
count=0

candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RIPPLE', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']

def countVowels(candidateWords):
    vowel=['A','E','I','O','U']

    for index in range (len(candidateWords)):

        if vowel in candidateWords[0]:
            count=count+1
            return count
            print(count)
        else:
            return False
```

When I trying to execute this code part nothing is displayed actually  I needed to get count of value of "HELLO" word

Comment: First qustion is GOODBYE counted as three vowels or only as two different vowels?

Comment: vowel should be a string 'AEIOU' and you need to test each letter from 'HELLO' against it. Aka: 'H' in 'AEIOU'? 'E' in 'AEIOU'? and so on.
Second you are using return before the print, that print is never going to run, as the function returns here.

Comment: consider as three vowels

Answer (score 1):

the main reason nothing is displayed is because you havent called the function after defining it. there are other mistakes in there too.

here is the correct code to print the vowel count for all the words in the word list:

```
candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RIPPLE', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
vowel=['A','E','I','O','U']

def countVowels(candidateWords):

    for index in range(len(candidateWords)):
        count=0
        for _ in candidateWords[index]:
            if _.upper() in vowel:
                count += 1
        print(candidateWords[index], 'has', count, 'vowels')

countVowels(candidateWords)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum` function with a generator expression that iterates through each letter of each word in the list and tests if the letter is a vowel:

```
def countVowels(candidateWords):
    return sum(letter in 'AEIOU' for word in candidateWords for letter in word)
```

Comment: OP might want count for each word